# How to take backup of a shell?

Tags: linux, unix, shell, console

I was working on a shell and got some weird exceptions in my program.

Just as a reference, I want to save all that is there on my shell to a text file. I do not just want the command history but also all the results that those commands produced at the shell.

**Is there some built-in utility to do this?** I have kept the shell open for now, so that I can take the backup. Also, I am using xterm and it does not allow selecting all the way upto the top of the shell, so the ultimate way is to take the backup one screen at a time. Any suggestions?

The shell looks like

[image]

Comment: What shell are you using? Bash, Bourne, Korn, Z, C, etc.? I think when you're saying "shell" you mean "terminal" instead. What error message did you get? You want to save a copy of output after-the-fact? Normally, before-hand you could use `script` to save the input and output.

Comment: Also, are you actually using "xterm", or are you using that to refer to something like Konsole or the like?  The terminal emulator Konsole (and others like it) have the ability to do logging, and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `script` may be of some use here

http://linux.die.net/man/1/script

And xterm should have the ability to select al you want.  I'd check your flags, including `-sl NUMBER`, `-sb`

Comment: `script` is a nice find, but it has to be started beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

To copy the whole window content, including the scrollback, select the last line (by dragging the left mouse button or by triple-clicking the left mouse button), then use the scroll bars to scroll to the top and right-click in the top left corner. Note that unlike the methods below, this will only show the final result as plain text: it won't show things that were displayed then erased, and it won't show colors and other formatting.

---

To avoid this in the future you can try this.

- Run your session inside `script`. Logging a shell session is `script`'s goal in life.
- Run your session inside `screen`. It has several commands that can help you, including `C-a h` to write a “screenshot” into a file, and `C-a H` to start logging all subsequent output to a file.
- Some terminal emulators have a logging facility. In xterm, you can turn it on by checking “Log to File” in the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+left-mouse-button menu; all subsequent terminal output is logged. With the `-l` option, this is done for the whole session.

Comment: +1 And moved the part that might help in this case (wanting to capture an existing session) to the top